# Hausdorff measure of intersections

Tags: measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Suppose I have $3$ sets $A,B,C$ all contained in let's say $\mathbb{R}^k$ and I have the relation that with respect to some dimension function $f$

$H^f(A \cap B)= H^f(A \cap C)$

where $H^f(A)$ denotes the usual Hausdorff $f$-measure of the set $A$.

Is it true that

$H^f(B)= H^f(C)$.

If not what extra conditions are required for this conclusion?

Comment: What if this intersection is empty?

Comment: That's a good point IIya, 
in order for the condition $H^f(A \cap B)= H^f(A \cap C)$ to still hold though both intersections would have to be empty but does that lead necessarily to $H^f(B)= H^f(C)$ I'm not sure?
Also if we assume the intersections are not empty what happens?

Comment: My point is that a single intersection is not enough to judge about the whole set. Unless A contains a union of both, but then it's a trivial statement.

Comment: I see your point now IIya and it's a very good point thank you. So that's the cases where $A$ contains none of $B$ or $C$ and the case where $A$ contains all of $B$ and all of $C$. What about the case where $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ and $A \cap C \neq \emptyset$ but neither $B$ or $C$ are contained completely in $A$

Comment: From little I know about GMT, I guess that the Lebesgue measure (just a length of an interval) is a valid special case of your $H^f$. Think of $B = [0, 100], C = [100, 101]$ and $A = [99, 101]$